# How is variation in genes related to self-awareness?

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-mind

I sometimes wonder if "I" would have existed if another sperm had fertilized the egg that was to become "me".  Is this even answerable in any meaningful way? I sit here and experience myself as a unique individual and I speculate that everybody else feels the same about their own unique consciousness and self-awareness. So if a different sperm had fertilized the egg that was there when I was conceived, would "I" have come into existence nine months later, but with a different set of genes?

Comment: This is a great philosophy question --I gave you an upvote for that --but it's not a good fit for this forum because there is no defined answer.  You might manage to keep it from being closed if you make it more specific --*i.e.* "what would philosopher X say about this question?" or "how could we address this question in light of X-ism?"

Comment: If a different sperm from same the same man fertilized the same egg, 25% of the embryo's DNA would be different from yours. The result would be similar to your semi-identical twin. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin#Semi-identical_twins

Comment: You could also think about the differences and similarities among identical twins (same genetic info) and siblings (with 50% similar genetic info).

Answer (score 3):

Studies tend to show that about 50% of variability in behavioral traits is explained by genes and 50% by environment.  Unlike with identical twins, your other could have a pretty similar experience to you.  So, with 25% of your genes different, your other would be up to about 8x more similar to you than a random person is, and would have many of the same experiences and memories.

But of course that very-similar-person's consciousness wouldn't be yours; you are by hypothesis not around to experience anything.  You can't really arrange it so you can without breaking the whole premise.  So the other-you is identifiable as the most you-like entity in that hypothetical universe, and that is about as far as it goes.

Comment: While I would tend to agree with some of this. There seems to be a giant root assumption that goes unstated about the nature of consciousness and its relation to the physical brain. The seemingly appropriate follow-up question is this: did "I" exist a minute ago, a day ago, a year ago? It seems like  answers as to why these questions are affirmative or negative would explain what your answer really means.

Comment: I think the answer to the question "did 'I' exist a minute ago, a year ago" is yes. At least in the context of my own self-awareness and memory of who I was a minute ago.

Comment: Although my experiences and physical parts are constantly changing I still think I retain a definite self-awareness that is specific and unique to "me". On the other hand I suppose a grain of sand on the beach is also unique - just as unique as a particular mosquito, bacteria, or cloud formation. Could it be that this concept we call "self-awareness" is merely a kind of biological feed-back loop or memory polling function that evolved as just another component in our biology - from single cells all the way to warm blooded mammals with backbones and a self-polling memory function in our brain?

Comment: @Steved'Apollonia that may all be true... but I think Rex needs to indicate *his* answer to this question and explain why the different genetic material matters in a way that different matter does not.

Comment: @virmaior - I'm arguing that the premise makes it an unanswerable question when asking it in the "did 'I' exist a year ago" sense.  When asking it in another sense, we can tell that this person is likely to be Steve-like, but somewhat distinct: perhaps less different than identical twins (save for looks) are to each other, but there still would be substantial differences based on the genetic contribution.